# Interactive editing of feature class table

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, attribute-table, editing, interaction

I would like to create an arcpy tool that would allow me to iterate through a given feature class, probably using a For: statement, but that would pause after each instance to allow me to make changes to the table value for the particular instance. For example, I would like to iterate through a list of places and make changes to the field 'Mayor_name' manually, one at a time, and then press a key to summon the next record/row. This would then zoom to the next instance. Are there any input methods that could be used or any other helpful suggestions?

Comment: I'd use data driven pages to do this. It's not a task for arcpy

Answer (score 0):

I do not think ArcPy is useful here.  I think the functionality that you seek is already available through attribute table editing.

Try this:

1. Open the Attribute Table you wish to edit
2. Start Editing the workspace that contains the feature class for that attribute table
3. Right-click on the cell at the left-hand end of the first row of the attribute table and Zoom To it.
4. Click into the Mayor_name field and type in its value
5. Repeat for each row in the attribute table
6. Save Edits and Stop Editing

Comment: Thanks. I realize I can do this as you describe (that's how I have been doing it), but I would like to reduce the number of keystrokes to one, say by hitting the "return" key after each field edit, and avoid having to click on the next entry and select zoom. Just trying to make a series of successive edits quicker.